# Node.js API with JWT authentication

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I have a Node.js Express API that doesn't have any security and now I'm looking to patch on JWT-based authorization.

I have it working (using the code below) for one method. Is there an easy way to apply this to all the methods? e.g., maybe using app.all? Or do I have to add the code to every method?

```
app.get('/people/:id', ensureToken, (req, res, next) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  getPerson(id, (err, people) => {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
      return;
    }

    jwt.verify(req.token, process.env.JWT_KEY, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(403);
      } else {
        res
          .status(200)
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
          .set("Connection", "close")
          .send(person);
      }
    });
  });
});

function ensureToken(req, res, next) {
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thx for the quick reply. I’ll try it tonight

Comment: With this you're still going to be including `jwt.verify` in your route.

Comment: What I do not like in this solution is the lack of a check on the authorization type. In this concrete example we should assure us that `bearer[0]` really contains the keyword "bearer" (case insensitively)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt)

You can use this as middleware as well:

```
app.get('/people/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res, next) => { });
```

The advantage to this over using `app.use` is that you can specify which routes should be authenticated.  i.e., you can exclude a `login` or `registration` route. without having to hack in checks like `if (req.path == '/login')`The other advantage is that using [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) you can later add additional authentication methods, should you choose.  There's also quite a bit of community support.

Comment: Thanks, I've already been considering it as my long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented it with app.all, excluding the login route from the check:

```
app.all(process.env.API_BASE + "*", (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.path.includes(process.env.API_BASE + "login")) return next();

    return auth.authenticate((err, user, info) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) {
            if (info.name === "TokenExpiredError") {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Your token has expired. Please generate a new one" });
            } else {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: info.message });
            }
        }
        app.set("user", user);
        return next();
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

The full solution here: https://jonathas.com/token-based-authentication-in-nodejs-with-passport-jwt-and-bcrypt/